# cannot draw tower after mouseclicked

Tags: java

I have been working on a Tower Defense. The issue right now is that my tower is not being drawn to board after mouse click. It was working before, but not working right now!

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    Towers.posX = (int)(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX()) - 321;
    Towers.posY = (int)(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY()) - 100;
    TowerArray.add(Towers);

    if (TowerArray.size() > 0) {
        // if(TowerArray[i] != EnemyArray[j]) {
        System.out.println(Towers.posX + " " + Towers.posY);
        Towers.Draw(View.background.getGraphics());
        // } else {
        // System.out.println("Cant place tower on enemy path");
    }

    Towers.Draw(Controller.View.background.getGraphics());
}
```

Comment: `View.background.getGraphics()` is worrying. Are you using a `BufferStrategy` or are you drawing directly to a component?

Comment: If it was working before and recently failed, what was the most recent tested working `mouseClicked()` method?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yeah we dropped making a grid system, so we are printing right on the screen.

Comment: @FailingCoder we have not touched this code above, but we have built more features like adding enemies etc... platforms and stuff.

Comment: `getGraphics` is NOT how you should be doing custom painting, your fighting the painting sub system (and are now losing).  See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works and how you should work with it